# I am neither robber nor police. Neither I am robber nor police

Tags: word-order, neither-nor, correlating-conjunctions

Which sentence should be correct?

> I am **neither** robber **nor** police.
>   **Neither** I am robber **nor** police.

I often saw ( neither....nor) is sometimes used in the middle of sentences and sometimes it is used out of sentences as I added two examples here.

Would you like to tell me the reason behind this problem place?

Comment: Neither is that the only possibility: there are others. Nor shall I list them all here.

Comment: You might find [this web lesson](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/either-or-neither-nor) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence **"I am neither robber nor police."** is the correct form, but the way that I would say it is" **"I am neither a robber nor the police."**

The problem with the second sentence is that the verb is out of place.  A *Neither/Nor* phrases represents two possible ways to end a sentence:
**"I am not a robber."** and **"I am not the police."**, but then combines them into the same sentence.

Using an *Either/Or* or *Neither/Nor* phrase is a way of combining two different sentences into one.  This sentence combines **"I am not a robber."** with **"I am not the police."**.  The combined sentence now has one beginning: **"I am not..."** and two endings: **"...a robber."** and **"...the police."**.

*Either/Or* lets you have two endings to the same sentence, and so it becomes: **"I am not either a robber or the police."**  This sounds awkward to our ears which is why we have *Neither/Nor* for negatives.  The **"not"** distributes over the *either* and the *or* and we get *neither* and *nor* and thus:

**"I am neither a robber nor the police."**

Comment: The article is required.  "I am not robber."  is incorrect.   "I am not robber and police" is incorrect.  "I am neither robber nor police" is incorrect.  You must use the article here.

Answer (score -1):

For the second sentence: “Neither I am robber nor police”
You can convert as:

> “Neither am I a robber nor a police.” = inversion mood